# Embedding of $CP^2/CP^1$ into euclidean space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, embeddings, projective-varieties

Is there a "nice" embedding of $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2/\,\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$ into $\mathbb{R}^8$?

Comment: What does $/$ mean here?

Comment: @IgorRivin: I think $X/Y$ means that we collapse $Y$ to a point, and take the quotient topology from the obvious map $X \to X/Y$.

Comment: Of course, quotients depend on the way a subspace is embedded. But if I take the standard embetting, then I obtain $\Bbbk P^n$ from $\Bbbk P^{n-1}$ by attaching one cell. So should the quotient not just be a sphere $S^{n\dim\Bbbk}$? Or do you mean something different?

Comment: @User371 The attaching map may be twisted, but if you contract its target space to a point, you don't see that any longer. Also, from the long exact reduced homology sequence you get $H_1(\mathbb R P^2/\mathbb R P^1;\mathbb Z/2)=0$.

Comment: I can't understand the question. If by $\mathbb RP^2/\mathbb RP^1$ you mean the space that is obtained by collapsing $\mathbb RP^1$  to a point, then this is obviously a sphere $\mathbb S^2$ and not $\mathbb RP^2$. There is only one way to glue the boundary of a disk to a point!!! So please do explain what you mean by /.

Comment: @Sebastian You are right! I don't know what was I thinking. I striped the question off the mistake.

Comment: The comments remain: if $/$ means what Ben McKay says, then $\Bbb{CP}^2/\Bbb{CP}^1 \cong S^4$, and surely this is not what you're asking about. So what do you mean?